# string is undefined in a forEach

Tags: javascript

very simple code :

```
var imagesInNewDB = new Array;
prodata.forEach(function(x){
    console.log(x.name);
    var str = x.name;
    console.log(typeof x.name);
    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
})
```

Typeof x.name displays "string".

for example 
console.log(prodata[10]); displays:

brand

```
"cool brand"
```

fun

```
"0"
```

id

```
10
```

imageName

```
"remi.png"
```

length

```
"6'2"
```

model

```
"Remix"
```

name

```
"kevin john"
```

pertinence

```
"4"
```

photocredits

```
"asdseesp"
```

thick

```
"2''1/2"
```

volume

```
"0"
```

weight

```
"86"
```

width

```
"19''1/8"
```

But I get the error :

TypeError: str is undefined

Why ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the defintion of `prodata`?

Comment: Are you trying to use `str` after the `forEach` is done? It's a local variable to the function, so it's not in scope outside the function.

Comment: @hindmost What difference does it make? `console.log()` is showing that the `name` property exists.

Comment: One or more of your objects does not have a name attribute.
Edit: looking at your results, assuming I am understanding correctly, it is because your 10 value is not a string.  do var str = x.name + "";
can you post a fiddle as well?

Comment: print str and typeof str after you set it to x.name

Comment: Surely x.name is undefined/null for one of the items in prodata?

Comment: if I print `str` and `typeof str`, I get the good x.name and the type if `string`

Comment: Please privide the minimum code required to reproduce this error. We don't know what prodata contains.

Comment: @Moob exact !! prodata[0].name is undefined. how do I circumvent this ?

Comment: add if (x.name) {var str = x.name; }

Comment: if(str) str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');

the root of your issue is you are trying to execute a function on an undefined var.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody I found that the first value prodata[0].name was undefined.
Solution :

```
var imagesInNewDB = new Array;
prodata.forEach(function(x){
    console.log(x.name);
    if (typeof x.name !== 'undefined'){
        var str = x.name;
        console.log(typeof x.name);
        str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    }
})
```

Comment: I would do if (x.name) { }
x.name could also be null, which would result in the same error.